# How to add values of one column based on conditional statement of another column that has blank cells?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, summarize

I'm trying to subset data based on a conditional statement of a column that has blank values which means the employee logged in multiple times on a work order. An example data set is shown below:

```
 employee_name <- c("Person A","Person A","Person A","Person A","Person A", "Person B","Person B","Person B")
 work_order <- c("WO001","WO001","WO001","WO002","WO003","WO001","WO003", "WO003")
 num_of_points <- c(40,"","",64,25,20,68,"")
 time <- c(10, 30, 15, 20, 25, 5, 15, 30)
final_summary <- data.frame(employee_name,work_order,num_of_points, time)
    View(final_summary)
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOsY9.jpg)

Basically, I want to sum up the points and time by selecting all rows with points > 30, then grouped by Employee Name and Work Order which should return this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br2eM.jpg)

I can do the summarize function properly, but when I perform the initial subset, it excludes the blank rows for num_of_points and thus does not compute all the adjacent time (in minutes) values. This makes sense because subset(num_of_points > 30) only finds anything greater than 30. How can I tweak this to include the blank rows so I can successfully filter the data in order to compute the sum of time accurately, grouped by unique work order and employee name?

Comment: Do you sum the all the time or just when points > 30?

Comment: just when points >30, see akrun's answer for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conver the `num_of_points` to `numeric` class, grouped by 'employee_name', 'work_order', get the `sum` of 'num_of_points' where it is greater than 30, and the `sum` of 'time', then `filter` out the rows where 'num_of_points' are 0

```
library(dplyr)
final_summary %>% 
   mutate(num_of_points = as.numeric(num_of_points)) %>% 
   group_by(employee_name, work_order) %>% 
   summarise(num_of_points = sum(num_of_points[num_of_points> 30], 
            na.rm = TRUE), time = sum(time)) %>%
   filter(num_of_points > 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   employee_name [2]
#  employee_name work_order num_of_points  time
#  <chr>         <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Person A      WO001                 40    55
#2 Person A      WO002                 64    20
#3 Person B      WO003                 68    45
```

Comment: thank you out of all the options, this one was the correct and simplest way. My initial code was very similar, but was missing the filter aspect which conjugated the time values accurately. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In base R you will do:

```
aggregate(.~employee_name + work_order, type.convert(final_summary), sum, subset = num_of_points>30)
  employee_name work_order num_of_points time
1      Person A      WO001            40   10
2      Person A      WO002            64   20
3      Person B      WO003            68   15
```

Comment: The computation of time is still inaccurate. It doesn't add up all the values

Answer (score 0):

You can `aggregate` `num_of_points` and  `time` separately and `merge` the results.

```
merge(aggregate(num_of_points~employee_name + work_order, final_summary, 
                sum, subset = num_of_points>30),
       aggregate(time~employee_name + work_order, final_summary, sum))


#  employee_name work_order num_of_points time
#1      Person A      WO001            40   55
#2      Person A      WO002            64   20
#3      Person B      WO003            68   45
```